# Fix mypy error (got "signedinteger[Any]", expected "int")

Tags: python, mypy

Mypy says

```
first.py:11: error: Incompatible return value type (got "signedinteger[Any]", expected "int")  [return-value]
```

for the code

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def first_true_pos(x: npt.NDArray) -> int:
    """ for logical ndarray x, returns the index of the first True value
    if any, otherwise -1 """
    if len(x) < 1:
        return -1
    i = np.argmax(x)
    if x[i]:
        return i
    return -1
```

How can the code be fixed to satisfy mypy?

Comment: Can you do `return int(i)` to convert numpy's `signedinteger` to a regular `int` when you return it?

Comment: You could also type hint the return type as `int|np.int64` if you can't/don't want to change the existing code.